# Intuitive explanation for Nickell bias for fixed effect model estimated using dummy variables

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, endogeneity

If I'm estimated a regression with individual fixed effects and the lagged dependent variable, and I do the standard fixed effects transformation, I can see whether the bias comes from and it makes intuitive sense to me.

However, if I consider running a regression with individual dummy variables and the lagged dependent variable, I can't understand intuitively how a bias arises. My understanding is that the two regression specifications are analogous. If someone could provide me with some intuition for how Nickell bias arises with individual dummy variables and lagged dependent variables, I would greatly appreciate it.